# Lumen: Call trait helper file from model file not working

Tags: laravel, model, lumen

I am using my trait file "CommonTrait" inside my model file as below,

use in namespace,

```
use App\Http\Helpers\CommonTrait;
```

use inside class,

```
class LoginHistory extends Model
{
    use CommonTrait;
//use inside function as 
protected static function getList($req)
 {
      $reportFilter= $this->searchCommonFilter($reportDateFilter, $req); 
//this is my trait function
   }
}
```

but it gives me error like

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Comment: You can't use `$this` in static methods

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing a method from a static function, that's what the error message means, you can call other static functions/properties using `static::function() or static::property`.

In your case the function does not seems to be static, you need to either remove the static declaration from the fuinction or make the function which you are calling to a static one.